# Unity управление мышью под WSA

Tags: c#, unity3d

При сборке игры под Windows 10, метод

```
Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")
```

Ведет себя иначе, нежели в редакторе. Если мы блокируем курсор в любом месте экрана

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
```

И затем разлочиваем его

```
 Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
```

То в случае с редактором, курсор появляется ровно на середине экрана.
В случае с приложением под Windows 10, курсор появляется там где я его оставил. 
И при этом, когда мы блокируем курсор снова, у нас скачет

```
Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")
```

Как будто мы перетаскиваем мышь в центр.

Т.е. подытоживая.
Windows 10 app:
Если у нас мышь находится не по центру экрана, то во момент переключения состояния с None на Lock, исчезнувшая мышь, судя по всему, летит в центр экрана, создавая на

```
Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") и Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")
```

соответствующие значения.

В редакторе такой проблемы нет, несмотря на то что он тоже утаскивает мышь на центр экрана.

Как подобное решить? Я вижу несколько вариантов - либо не снимать показания с этих осей за кадр с Lock\Unlock, либо принудительно переставлять мышь в центр до Lock, как в редакторе. И то и другое вижу способом костыльным, буду рад увидеть предложения получше.

Comment: Кажется возвращать курсор в центр до выключения лока - менее костыльный метод, чем пропускать кадр в этом же месте:) Если не найдете лучшее решение - то можно эти махинации инкапсулировать и забыть про это.

Comment: Ну пишите проблему, пишите и версию Unity на которой получаете эту проблему

Comment: @Xumera_hZ 5.6.1f1

Comment: @MikhailEfremov А управлять курсором - это обращение к DLL самой системы, тем более что сам по себе Cursor.lock уже помещает мышь в центр. Только вот в редакторе оси при этом не задействуются, а на винде - задействуются.

Comment: Не пользуйтесь getAxis, а то привыкли к халяве) руками сами mousePosition и обертку над этим всем) Ну либо костыльте